# Drop-down link requires more than one click to open the pop up

Tags: html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have placed my user action links in a drop-down and it is supposed to open a pop-up form or dialog depending upon the link to be clicked. I am using bootstrap 4.

**Here is my code:**

```js
findUser($) {
        this.user.getById($.target.id).subscribe(res => {
            if (res.success === true) { this.isEdit = true; this.singleUser = res.data[0]; console.log('editable', this.singleUser) }
            else {
                this.toastr.error('An Error Occured, Please Try Again.', '', {
                    timeOut: 3000,
                    positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
                });
            }
        })
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<td>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-haspopup="true" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Action
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a id='{{item._id}}' (click)='findUser($event)' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#m_modal_5">Edit</a></li>
      <li><a id="{{item._id}}" (click)='deleteUser($event)'>Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</td>
```

Can anyone tell what is the issue? I have tried google but those solutions did not work.

**Solved:** 
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2294

Comment: Can you also post the code that handles the button request?

Comment: maybe this post will help you  [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853555/10424373)

Comment: Your snippet throws an exception: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"`

Comment: @JonathanWilson have you tried it in an angular app ? I am working in angular.

Comment: I'm not about to go create an angular app so that I can run your snippet.  That is your responsibility.  Truly, it's the least you can do if you expect help with your issue.  Plus, it's very possible that as you construct a simple (and runnable) demo of your issue, you discover the cause yourself.   What could be better than that? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This may also help you when asking questions in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I didn't asked  you to create an angular app to solve it. It has to do something with bootstrap, not angular.

Comment: If by "Solved" and a link you mean you have answered your own question, please add a full answer to assist others facing a similar issue and importantly to stop the question showing in searches as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have removed the data-toggle='dropdown' and it started working. Please follow this link for more information.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2294