# javascript: why do I need to click twice to change display property?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a menu with the property `display: none;` and a javascript in an external file that changes that property.

```js
let montreMenu = function(){
  var monMenu = document.querySelector('.popupmenu')
  if (monMenu.style.display === 'none'){
    monMenu.style.display = 'flex'
  }else{
    monMenu.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="apparition_popupmenu" onclick="montreMenu()" >Click
</span>
<nav class="popupmenu">
 <span>nav Data</span>
</nav>
```

It works, except that upon page load, I need to click on the span `apparition_popupmenu` twice for the toggle to take effect. Why is this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript onclick requires two clicks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852932/javascript-onclick-requires-two-clicks)

Comment: Add the display:none as default. If it's not set, it will set to "none" according to your code.

Comment: Because read access to `monMenu.style.display` only reads inline styles, not styles coming from your stylesheet.

Comment: Check my answer, pls. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Toggle a class! `monMenu.classList.toggle("active");` no worrying about state and read styles.

Comment: Hi again. Check out my second solution (on tip @epascarello). It will be better than checking the styles attribute. Everything works through the css classes. Better use the second solution.

Comment: thanks @s.kuznetsov. Does this change anything in terms of speed or stability?

Comment: Both solutions are stable, but in time the solution with the `toggle()` method wins, since there is no checking of the current mapping via **if**. In general, there is no specific implementation standard. The programmer himself chooses the method of implementing this or that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, most likely, you are specifying `display: none` in **css**, but in js logic you are referring to **styles**. Therefore, at first, on the first click, you get the `display: none`, and on the second click, the `display: flex`.

You can use method `getComputedStyle()` to check the css style. Like this:

```
if (window.getComputedStyle(monMenu).display === 'none') { ... }
```

Also, the questioned example:

```js
let montreMenu = function(){
  var monMenu = document.querySelector('.popupmenu')
  if (window.getComputedStyle(monMenu).display === 'none'){
    monMenu.style.display = 'flex'
  }else{
    monMenu.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```css
.popupmenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="apparition_popupmenu" onclick="montreMenu()" >Click</span>
<nav class="popupmenu">popup</nav>
```

Following the advice from the comment above, I made a second solution with method `toggle()`. This method adds / removes a class like a switch. And checking the current state of the **display** by the condition `if` is not required. It is only necessary to add the class of the active state to the css. Like this:

```
.popupmenu.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```js
let montreMenu = function(){
  var monMenu = document.querySelector('.popupmenu');
  monMenu.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.popupmenu {
  display: none;
}

.popupmenu.active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<span id="apparition_popupmenu" onclick="montreMenu()" >Click</span>
<nav class="popupmenu">popup</nav>
```